# Bad Request on simple POST Request

Tags: rest, spring-boot, post

I have broke it down to a minimum and still don't know why this happens.
I have the following method in my controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/myGreatCall")
public String getDynamicData(@RequestBody DataRequest dr) {
    return dr.toString();
}
```

Using the following simple class:

```java
public class DataRequest {
    private String type;
    //Getters and setters here
}
```

Now if I try to call this, I get an error 400 as the response.

```js
let url = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host+"/myGreatCall";

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", url, true);

    request.onload = function () {
        console.log(request.response); //Here I read the reponse and get the error 404
    };

    // This is the data I send as the body
    let data = JSON.stringify(
        {
            type: "myType"
        }
    );


    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.send(data);
```

Now from the error I suspect that for some reason it cant map my json object into the java object, but I have no idea why.

I tested the following:

- do the request without the Method Parameter, that worked
- different data types in the java class
- handing over a hardcoded string '{\"type\":\"myType\"}' to the #send()

Any Ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: is there any detail in your server log?

Comment: Also, if you have a non default constructor for DataRequest you will get this error. Add a default constructor if that's the case.

Comment: @codebrane yes there is a default constructor. DataRequest is actually annotated with `@Data` from lombok and contains nothing other.
Logs say nothing. I gotta check the logs with debug level and will write if there is something special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok seems to be something weird. I dont know what caused it, but after a PC restart it worked fine.

Comment: You can also perform clean and rebuild, sometimes helpful

Answer (score 0):

It may be down to JSON serialization. Try this:

```
let data = JSON.stringify(
        {
            "type": "myType"
        }
    );
```

Comment: Nope didnt work. I also debugged the "data" I had and it was already fine. Tried it anyways.